# How to add unmanaged dll to show up in Add Reference's COM tab

Tags: .net, com, reference, phash

I am currently trying to use `pHash.dll` on [http://phash.org](http://phash.org/)

Unfortunately it was written in C++, I'd have to use `DLLImport`

But the problem I am having is how to register `pHash.dll` (compiled thru VS2010/C++)
I've tried to register using `regsrv32` and have been fruitless giving an error message.

[image]

Now, How can i register `pHash` to show up in COM tab?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DLL in question exports flat APIs. The Add COM References Tab is for DLLs that expose COM objects. Instead of using Add Reference to refer to the DLL, you need to write a pinvoke declaration to let .NET know about your flat API.

Here's a helpful article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx

Martyn