# Using pHash from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, c++, dllimport

I am trying to use [pHash](http://phash.org) from .NET

First thing I tried was to register (regsvr32) `phash.dll` and asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233343/how-to-add-unmanaged-dll-to-show-up-in-add-references-com-tab)
Second of all, i was trying to import using [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) as shown below.

```
    [DllImport(@".\Com\pHash.dll")]
    public static extern int ph_dct_imagehash(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string file, 
        UInt64 hash);
```

But when i try to access the method above during run-time, following error message shows up.

```
    Unable to find an entry point named 'ph_dct_imagehash' in DLL '.\Com\pHash.dll'.
```

What does "entry point" means and why am I getting the error?

Thank you.

**FYI** - Here is the full source code

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace DetectSimilarImages
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport(@".\Com\pHash.dll")]
        public static extern int ph_dct_imagehash(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string file, 
            UInt64 hash);


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                UInt64 hash1 = 0, hash2 = 0;
                string firstImage = @"C:\Users\dance2die\Pictures\2011-01-23\177.JPG";
                string secondImage = @"C:\Users\dance2die\Pictures\2011-01-23\176.JPG";
                ph_dct_imagehash(firstImage, hash1);
                ph_dct_imagehash(secondImage, hash2);

                Debug.WriteLine(hash1);
                Debug.WriteLine(hash2);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Did you compile the DLL yourself? If so, did you take care to properly export the relevant function?

Comment: @konrad: I compiled the source myself but i am lost of what you said on "properly export the relevan functions" because I am not familiar with C++ at all...

Comment: @Sung Then the fix is easy: *don’t* compile the library yourself. Use the precompiled binary.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still was not able to resolve `Unable to find an entry point named 'ph_dct_imagehash' in DLL '.\Com\pHash.dll'.` eror even with pre-compiled dlls

Comment: Note that the second argument to `ph_dct_imagehash` should be `out UInt64 hash` rather than `UInt64 hash`.

Comment: @ildjarn : thank you for the correction.  But even though I have tried with new argument, I am still getting the error.  So for now I have contacted PHash developer and see what I doing wrong.

Comment: @Sung : I knew it wouldn't fix your present, hence posting a comment rather than an answer; just thought it was worth mentioning. ;-]

Comment: @ildjam:Thank you for mentioned it.  i also wasn't sure so I contacted the pHash developer and he told me that DllImport statement should be like `[DllImport("pHash", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
 public static extern int ph_dct_imagehash(string file, ref ulong hash);`

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/ludoviclefevre/phash-integration-in-csharp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The current Windows source code project (as of 7/2011) on [phash.org](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) does not seem to export the ph_ API calls from the DLL. You will need to add these yourself by __declspec(dllexport) at the beginning of the line in pHash.h like so:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int ph_dct_imagehash(const char* file,ulong64 &hash);
```

You should then see the export show up in the DLL using [dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS pHash.dll
...
Dump of file pHash.dll
...
          1    0 00047A14 closedir = @ILT+2575(_closedir)
          2    1 00047398 opendir = @ILT+915(_opendir)
          3    2 00047A4B ph_dct_imagehash = @ILT+2630(_ph_dct_imagehash)
          4    3 000477B2 readdir = @ILT+1965(_readdir)
          5    4 00047A00 rewinddir = @ILT+2555(_rewinddir)
          6    5 000477AD seekdir = @ILT+1960(_seekdir)
          7    6 00047AFA telldir = @ILT+2805(_telldir)
```

You should now be able to use this call from C#.

however...

I am getting a crash in the CImg code when I try to call this, so it seems there is some [more work to do here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001816/loading-pngs-with-cimg)...

Comment: This crashes for me in png_read_info(), but it seems to be working OK for JPGs

Comment: PNG seems to require some extra steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001816/loading-pngs-with-cimg

Comment: I was able to see ' 3    2 00047A4B ph_dct_imagehash = @ILT+2630(_ph_dct_imagehash) ' after doing dumpbin but I still cannot dllimport phash.dll.

Comment: What happened here is that, I didn't all dependant dlls and other libraries.
After fixing that issue, Now I am getting another error