# How would you declare DLL import signature?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, dllimport

this is a follow-up post of [Using pHash from .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254447/using-phash-from-net)

How would you declare following C++ declaration in .NET?

```
int ph_dct_imagehash(const char* file,ulong64 &hash);
```

So far i have

```
[DllImport(@"pHash.dll")]
public static extern int ph_dct_imagehash(string file, ref ulong hash);
```

But I am now getting following error for

```
ulong hash1 = 0, hash2 = 0;
string firstImage = @"C:\Users\dance2die\Pictures\2011-01-23\177.JPG";
string secondImage = @"C:\Users\dance2die\Pictures\2011-01-23\176.JPG";
ph_dct_imagehash(firstImage, ref hash1);
ph_dct_imagehash(secondImage, ref hash2);
```

[image]

It basically says that my declartion of ph_dtc_imagehash is wrong.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: What .dlls did you need in order to get this working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stack imbalance indicates that the C++ code uses `cdecl` and your C# uses `stdcall` calling convention.  Change your `DLLImport` to this:

```
[DLLImport(@"pHash.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

The function signature in C# (return value and parameters) is otherwise correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check the calling convention. If you don't specify one on the DllImport attribute, it defaults to WinApi (stdcall). The C snippet you posted doesn't specify a calling convention, and at least in VC++ the default calling convention is cdecl.

So you should try:

```
[DllImport(@"pHash.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int ph_dct_imagehash(string file, ref ulong hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting `DllImportAttribute.CharSet` property to `CharSet.Auto` as if you don't specify it, it will default to `Ansi`. This may be causing issues as your declaration seems to be fine.

Even if this is not the issue, take habit of specifying the `CharSet` property whenever a Dll function deals with text.

Comment: The function takes a char* though, so `Ansi` is the right setting here.