# pHash image comparison implementation in C#

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, image, image-processing

For our face detection system, we are looking for a `C#` implementation similar to [pHash](http://phash.org/). As it can be seen on `pHash` page, by using the different forms of the `Image sets` on [download page](http://phash.org/download/), the system compare two images and detect if both are  similar to each other or not even if the same image is `rotated`, `compressed`, `blurred`, etc. So, we need such a kind of implementation in `C#`, but unfortunately have not found on the web. Could you please clarify us about whether or not there is an example in `C#`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use PInvoke with the native dll? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254447/using-phash-from-net

Answer (score 0):

I've come across an implementation that has 3 different variations of pHash. Pls check this out https://github.com/coenm/ImageHash